# Put across position

Tags: phrasal-verbs

As for the usage of *put across* (phrasal verb) which one is correct?

> 'I have to study more so I can **put across** my ideas well.'

Or

> I have to study more so I can **put** my ideas **across** well.'

P.S. when Googling, there are examples of separated 'put something across' but also there are instances that they stick together. Any other tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your choice. The separated version is the more common, especially when the object phrase is short.  If the object phrase becomes lengthy, you could keep **put across** together. But it's a stylistic decision, not a grammatical one.

> He wanted to use the Tuesday open meeting to **put** his ideas relating to the development of a high-speed city-wide network with free access for all citizens on weekends **across** to City Council.

There, you might rephrase:

> He wanted to use the Tuesday open meeting **to put across to City Council** his ideas relating to the development of a high-speed city-wide network with free access for all citizens on weekends.

P.S. In that case, not only would you be keeping the phrasal verb **put across** together, you would be moving the prepositional phrase **to City Council**, which refers to the recipients of what is put across, so that it, too, is not stranded after the long  phrase containing the object.